# How to run specific tests based on settings in selenium

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, selenium, mstest

I am trying to run tests tests basedon app.config settings. Is it possible to do so. e.g

I want to run following tests if value is cars
   TestMethod()
   Test1
   TestMethod()
   test2
   TestMethod()
   test3

want to run following tests if value is engines
TestMethod()
test2

want to run following tests if value is fireengines
TestMethod()
test1
TestMethod()
test4

Any idea how can I achieve this by using vs2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly a function of your chosen unit testing framework. MSTest has the [TestCategory attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx). You'd mark your test methods with the category you want them in and when you run your tests you'd specify the desired category.